# cURL - download multiple files and specify output names

Tags: bash, curl

I have list of URLs with range in `{}`. I can download them with cURL in bash, but problem is output. I can use #1, but I need to have files named with different names (I have stored those names in array). How can change output names for multiple files ?

I have tried o download file by file, but that is about 40% slower, than multiple download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over two arrays, one with your URLs to download and another with your desired filenames, launching subprocesses that will run in parallel to download the files.

```
#!/bin/sh

# array of URLs
urls=( http://www.example.com/file1.zip http://www.example.com/file2.zip http://www.example.com/file3.zip )
# names of downloaded files
names=( myname1.zip myname2.zip myname3.zip )

for ((i = 0; i < ${#urls[@]}; ++i)); do
    printf "Launching subprocess to DL %s to %s\n" "${urls[i]}" "${names[i]}"
    curl -s -o "${names[i]}" "${urls[i]}" &
done
```

Or try something like this if you want it to be similar to using {} w/ curl:

```
#!/bin/sh

# desired filenames
names=( myname0.zip myname1.zip myname2.zip )

for (( i = 0; i < ${#names[@]}; ++i )); do
  printf "Launching subprocess to DL http://example.com/file%s.zip to %s\n" "$i" "${names[i]}"
  curl -s -o "${names[i]}" http://example.com/file"$i".zip &
done
```

Comment: Not the best solution. With this you create A LOT OF process in memory. In others words, for 100 files your create 100 curls commands. This can really be a problem.